# Meteor onRendered Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, meteor-helper

Am having an issue of using JQuery plugin in meteor template. I tried [this](http://www.listjs.com/docs/plugins/pagination) plugin.

```
 <div id="listId">
  <ul class="list">
      // A bunch of items
  </ul>
  <ul class="pagination"></ul>
</div>

<script>
  var options = {
    valueNames: [ 'name', 'category' ],
    page: 3,
    plugins: [
      ListPagination({})
    ]
  };

  var listObj = new List('listId', options);
</script>
```

I put about javascript code in onRendered.

```
Template.MyTemplate.onRendered({
    listObj = new List('listId', {
      valueNames: [ 'name', 'category' ],
      page: 3,
      plugins: [
        ListPagination({})
      ]
    });`enter code here`
});
```

But I am getting error.

```
MyTemplate.js:2:13: Unexpected token =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing object ({}) to onRendered function:

```
Template.MyTemplate.onRendered({
    listObj = new List('listId', {
      valueNames: [ 'name', 'category' ],
      page: 3,
      plugins: [
        ListPagination({})
      ]
    });
});
```

You should pass function:

```
Template.MyTemplate.onRendered(function() {
    listObj = new List('listId', {
      valueNames: [ 'name', 'category' ],
      page: 3,
      plugins: [
        ListPagination({})
      ]
    });
});
```